# ESXi Server shows "Storage: 0" after updating via vib

Tags: vmware-esxi, datastore

I'm kinda lost, my ESXi kungfu is not strong enough obviously.
What I did is put the server into maintenance and install the vib `ESXi600-201905001.zip` via `ssh://esxcli software vib install --depot=/vmfs/volumes/...zip` which worked fine and then I finished off by `reboot` but now I cannot see any storage anymore. `vSphere-Client` can also not find any drives, disk or such.

I tried some commands and recommended by the internet but none of them helped:

```
esxcfg-volume -l #shows nothing
esxcli storage vmfs extent list #shows nothing
esxcli storage vmfs snapshot list #shows nothing
```

the only command that shows something is
`esxcli storage filesystem list` but the volumes have no names anymore

```
Mount Point                                        Volume Name  UUID                                 Mounted  Type       Size      Free
-------------------------------------------------  -----------  -----------------------------------  -------  ----  ---------  --------
/vmfs/volumes/53604056-a33ee2a8-e6ca-0cc47aab4cfe               53604056-a33ee2a8-e6ca-0cc47aab4cfe     true  vfat  299712512  84172800
/vmfs/volumes/8b6b7ee9-eee037bd-f068-7adeee1c369e               8b6b7ee9-eee037bd-f068-7adeee1c369e     true  vfat  261853184  62386176
/vmfs/volumes/1461ebe2-641ebb2e-0a5a-58f5a4cbba15               1461ebe2-641ebb2e-0a5a-58f5a4cbba15     true  vfat  261853184  62996480
```

I have no clue how to debug this or mount it, so I hope one can lead me into the right direction how to make my ESXi see my VM's again. We had 2 datastores with raid1 and raid10 but when I try to add them via vSphere the disk list is empty.

ESXI

- shows no datastores:
  [image: no datastores]
- when trying to add a device:
  [image: no devices with free space]

vSphere

- also no datastores:
  [image: no persistent storage]
- when trying to add a device:
  [image: no disk/lun]

Thanks for hints, tips and workaround in advance :)

Comment: What does your 'storage adapters' tab look like? What version did you go from? Oh and what's the full HW spec?

Comment: from `6.0.0 Update 1` to `6.0.0 Update 3 (Build 13635687)`
the tab shows 11 vmhba `Wellsburg AHCI Controller`, 1 `iSCSI Software Adapter` and 1 `USB Storage Controller`

the system is a X10DRi with 2x Xeon E5-2623 v3, 64GB RAM and an Adaptec ASR-8805 - 12G SAS. One co-worker suggested that the drivers are incompatible with the update, but since it was just a minor-update with bug fixes, I'm not sure that's a possibility

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem was that the `AACRAID` needed an update.

To find the proper bundle, you have to check VMware HCL for IO Devices:
https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=io

I had to install the `Adaptec_Inc_bootbank_scsi-aacraid_6.0.6.2.1.57013-1OEM.600.0.0.2494585` offline bundle and now my storage is back at last.
Next ESXi update will be skipped :D